Cloning sheets doesn't clone Drawing part
In my workbook a need to clone worksheet and later replace their content. Unfortunatetly the Clone() method doesn't create a copy of the DrawingPart. When replacing an image in one sheet, the change appears in all twin sheets. Instection of the underlying Xml reviels, that they share the same DrawingPart.
This is my method.
    public static async void CloneSheet(SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet, string sheetName, string newSheetName) {
            // Get the source sheet
            var sheets = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets;
            var sourceSheet = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == sheetName);
            if (sourceSheet == null) {
                throw new ArgumentException($"Sheet with name {sheetName} does not exist.");
            }

            // Get the source worksheet part
            var sourceSheetPart = (WorksheetPart)spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sourceSheet.Id);

            // Create a new worksheet part
            var newSheetPart = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            newSheetPart.Worksheet = (Worksheet)sourceSheetPart.Worksheet.Clone();

            // Clone the relationships
            foreach (var rel in sourceSheetPart.Parts) {
                newSheetPart.AddPart(rel.OpenXmlPart, rel.RelationshipId);
            }

            // Clone DrawingsPart and its related ImageParts
            if (sourceSheetPart.DrawingsPart != null) {
                var sourceDrawingsPart = sourceSheetPart.DrawingsPart;
                DrawingsPart newDrawingsPart;
                
                if (newSheetPart.DrawingsPart == null) {
                    newDrawingsPart = newSheetPart.AddNewPart<DrawingsPart>();
                } else {
                    newDrawingsPart = newSheetPart.DrawingsPart;
                }

                newDrawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing = (WorksheetDrawing)sourceDrawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.Clone();

                var imagePartsToClone = sourceDrawingsPart.ImageParts.ToList();

                foreach (var imagePart in imagePartsToClone) {
                    var newImagePart = newDrawingsPart.AddImagePart(imagePart.ContentType);


                    using (var stream = imagePart.GetStream()) {
                            newImagePart.FeedData(stream);
                    }

                    // Update the BlipFill.Blip.Embed.Value to reference the new image part
                    foreach (var blip in newDrawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing.Blip>()) {
                        if (blip.Embed.Value == sourceDrawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart)) {
                            var newId = newDrawingsPart.GetIdOfPart(newImagePart);
                            blip.Embed.Value = newId;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Create a new sheet and add it to the workbook
            var newSheetId = spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newSheetPart);
            var newSheet = new Sheet {
                Id = newSheetId,
                SheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Max(s => s.SheetId.Value) + 1,
                Name = newSheetName // todo: Ensure the new sheet name is unique
            };

            sheets.Append(newSheet);

            // Save the workbook
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }

